# Update UI on Singleton property change without sharing dependency between Views

Tags: swift, user-interface, swiftui, dependencies, singleton

I want to make my UI update itself on singleton's class property change without passing the singleton object between views as .environmentObject or any another.

I have `NetworkManager` class, which is singleton:

```
final class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {
    let monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "NetworkManager")
    @Published var isConnected = true
    
    static let shared: NetworkManager = {
       NetworkManager()
    }()
    
    private init() {
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.isConnected = path.status == .satisfied
            }
        }
        
        monitor.start(queue: queue)
    }
}
```

Whenever `@Published var isConnected` property of this class changes, I want to update the UI for example with this piece of code: `SOME_VIEW.disabled(!NetworkManager.shared.isConnected)`
Unfortunately, `SOME_VIEW` is disabled only when I exit and entry this view once again. I want it to update itself in real time. Is it possible without `@EnvironmentObject` and only having my `NetworkManager` class as `Singleton`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ObservableObject` updates view only via `ObservedObject/StateObject/EnvironmentObject` (which are actually have same nature). That wrapper (one of them) actually observers changes in published properties and refreshes view.

So your case can be solved like

```
struct ParentView: View {
   @StateObject private var networkNanager = NetworkManager.shared  // << observer !!

   var body: some View {
     SOME_VIEW.disabled(!networkNanager.isConnected) // injects dependency !!
   }
}
```